# Is there difference between storage permission for Android 11 and Android 9?

Tags: android, permissions, storage

I use Sydney Delphi for Android. I set the storage permissions on the IDE. The Application run on Android 9, but not on Android 10 and 11. Have you an explanation please?

Comment: can you share your permission code please?

Comment: I use the permission component. Then code is::     MobilePermissions1.Dangerous.ReadExternalStorage := true;
  MobilePermissions1.Dangerous.WriteExternalStorage:=true;
    MobilePermissions1.Apply;